# Header property in the copy of OpenXML header is empty

Tags: c#, openxml

I need to add some text to the copy of the header

But when copying a header, the "Header" property in the copy is empty

I'm using OpenXML 2.0.5022.0

My code:

```
MemoryStream m_stream = new MemoryStream();
WordprocessingDocument docx = WordprocessingDocument.Create(m_stream, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
MainDocumentPart main_part = docx.AddMainDocumentPart();
main_part.Document = new Document{ Body = new Body() };

HeaderPart header_part = docx.MainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>();
header_part.Header = new Header(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text{ Text = "q" })));

HeaderPart new_h_part = main_part.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>();
new_h_part.FeedData(header_part.GetStream());
if (new_h_part.Header != null)
{
    //but header is null
}
```

Found the solution

After creation, the header must be explicitly stored in the DOM:

```
header_part.Header = new Header(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text{ Text = "q" })));
header_part.Header.Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the namespace.  Below is an example of an OpenXml file taken from the OpenXml Specficiation

```
<w:document xmlns:w="…">
  …
  <w:sectPr>
    <w:footerReference w:val="rId89" w:type="default"/>
    <w:footerReference w:val="rId90" w:type="even"/>
    <w:footerReference w:val="rId91" w:type="first"/>
    <w:type w:val="oddPage"/>
    <w:pgSz w:w="11909" w:h="16834" w:code="9"/>
    <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1152" w:bottom="1440"
    w:left="1152" w:header="720" w:footer="720" w:gutter="0"/>
    <w:lnNumType w:countBy="1"/>
    <w:pgNumType w:numFmt="lowerRoman"/>
    <w:cols w:space="720"/>
  </w:sectPr>
</w:document>
```